# CSS first-of-type and first-letter

Tags: css

I want to change the first letter of every chapter of my fanfiction using:

```
    #workskin .userstuff.module p:first-of-type::first-letter {
      font-size: 2.5em;
      line-height: 1;
      color: indianred;          
    }
```

However, the last chapter contains a div, and the first letter in the first paragraph of that div is also being styled. Why is this happening, and what do I have to add to my code to prevent it from happening short of styling that one letter individually?

ETA: The HTML goes something like this:

```
    <p>text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    <div>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    </div>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
```

To be clear, I ONLY want the first letter of the original paragraph to be styled, but the first letter of the first paragraph of the div is also being affected. Why?

Comment: Can you share the HTML code as well?

Comment: Maybe the `:not()` pseudo-selector can be helpful here?

Comment: `first-of-type` will take only first type not all `p` elements.

Comment: `div` inside `p` is invalid to start with so I would fix this first

Comment: @TemaniAfif He doesn't say the div is in a `p`... that's why we need a demo. It could be that the container is a `section` or another `div`

Comment: Paulie_D I think you may have stumbled onto the problem. The portion of the page we're allowed to style is only a part of the entire page. We have to add #workskin .user.module before each CSS code on our external CSS pages for the actual story part. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this:

```css
:not(div)>p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: indianred;
  line-height: 1;
}


/* It is like assign the css property for element p but `not` for `p`  `div`- being its parent */
```

```html
<p>pelement</p>
<p>pelement more text</p>
<p>more text pelement</p>
<p>pelement more text</p>
<div>
  <p>div content</p>
  <p>div content</p>
</div>
<p>ptext</p>
<p>pmore text</p>
<p>ptext</p>
<p>pmore text</p>
<div>
  <p>div content</p>
  <p>div content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I don't want the first letter of ALL paragraphs styled, just the first as I said. The problem is it's also styling the first letter of the first paragraph in the div as well.

Comment: @dustnik ok then, I have changed the code only for the first letter of that type, hope it looks good now? btw the code I added doesn't add the css value for the content within `div`.

Comment: Nope, that also knocked out the styling of all the first letters in all first paragraphs of every chapter. I think the problem has to do with the fact that the site only lets us style the section of the page that contains our story (they call it the #workskin .userstuff.module I guess I'll just have to style that one letter individually. Thanks for all your help, though.

Comment: Code can be written for the snippet you gave, not for the entire site, so the answer works as per the question, I am not asking you to accept this answer or vote! but the proper code should be shared to get it fixed. Please keep that in mind in future when you post the question, cheers.

Comment: Manjuboyz, sorry if I inadvertently left out some vital information that would make a difference in the answer. I'm rather new to this and hope you can forgive me. I corrected the CSS now in the original post, so if you know the answer to this, please won't you share it with me?

Comment: You have not defined those selector IDs in HTML however my answered code still works for this case take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/msjabcvk/27/

Comment: I see that the example works for you here. However, I tried using it after the #workskin .user.module part, both with a space and not a space, and it takes out the styling of the first letter altogether, not just the one in the div as desired.

Comment: in that case the HTML you shared above is not correct, I can able to fix only for the code which you shared not what you have in your project right?

Comment: I'm really confused here. The HTML is correct except that I changed the text which wouldn't make any difference. The #workskin .userstuff.module is part of the CSS, not the HTML

Comment: What I am trying to explain is the code `#workskin .userstuff.module` doesn't exist in the question, so these selector is used for some HTML tags right? I am asking you to share those HTML elements which got those selector used.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a negation if the `p` is a first-child of a `div`:

```
p:not(div > p:first-child):first-of-type::first-letter {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: indianred;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: You can't put a complex selector inside a `:not()` statement like that -

Comment: @Paulie_D Actually you can - see the syntax rules for `:not()` on MDN - you **can** use the child `>` selector and psuedo-class `:` selectors inside a `:not()` negation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: If you can demo this I'd believe you but complex selectors *are WD at the moment* - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mdeBWmW

Comment: only safari support this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's a selector **list** (i.e. a comma-separated list of selectors), that's not the same thing as a Complex Selector.

Comment: @Paulie_D Looks like you're right - I stand corrected.

Comment: a selector list is a generic definition that include comma separated simple, compound, **complex** selector. (check the specification: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation). Actually the not() is supported only with simple selector and the next level is to support selector list and a complex selector is a particular case of a selector list (only one selector inside a list)

Comment: I tried this solution, and it knocked out the styling of ALL the first letters of the first chapter paragraphs. So no, it doesn't work.